# Pausing setTimeout when .click (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, settimeout, slide

I have a jQuery script sliding through a few divs. The code is below. I have two issues I need to resolve:

1. Resetting or adding to the timer when a user clicks on a tab. At the moment, it may switch immediately to the next slide depending on where it is in the cycle.
2. Pausing the timer (i.e., clearing the timeout then restarting it) when a user is hovering over a particular slide.

To accomplish these, I gave setTimeout a variable ($theTimeout) and attempted to clearTimeout and then run show_cycle_elem() again. No matter how many different ways I tried to do it (by throwing my other events, such as the click, into functions, then calling them immediately after setTimeout, etc.), it didn't seem to work entirely right.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
var theId = 0;
function navClass(it){
    $('#hero nav a').removeClass('over');
    $(it).addClass('over');
}
$.fn.cycle = function(timeout){
    var $all_elem = $(this);
    show_cycle_elem = function(){
        if(theId == $all_elem.length) theId = 0;
        $all_elem.hide().eq(theId).fadeIn();
        navClass('#a' + theId);
        var $theTimeout = setTimeout(function(){show_cycle_elem(++theId)}, timeout);
    }
    show_cycle_elem();
}
$('div.hero_slide').cycle(10000);
$('#hero nav a').click( function(party){
    party.preventDefault();
    theId = this.id.substr(1);
    navClass($(this));
    $('.hero_slide').hide();
    $('#hero' + theId).fadeIn();
});
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I don't see good today, but where is your clearTimeout?

Comment: I didn't include any of the things I tried in order to clear the timeout, as none of them worked. My question is, in fact, where and how I should use the `clearTimeout($theTimeout)`

Comment: If you want to use $theTimeout from everywhere, then you must declare it global.

Comment: For one thing you need to declare `$theTimeout` in a scope that you can access at the time you want to clear it - not necessarily global: you could for example declare it in the same place as `theId`.

Comment: Right, but how do I do that if it's nested inside of show_cycle_elem(), inside of cycle()? Do I do `var $theTimeout;` under `var theId = 0`, then just set $theTimeout to setTimeout(...) in show_cycle_elem()?

Comment: Do you want to build a plugin or a custom solution? If it is a custom solution I don't see any reason why the declaration must be nested. In case of a plugin you should rethink your complete architecture, because then you need to implement some kind of attributes that can start and stop the timeout.

Comment: Sven, cycle() may possibly be used elsewhere, as well, so the nesting is necessary. At any rate, I was successfully able to clearTimeout($theTimeout) and then merely start cycle() again after, for both .click and .mouseover/.mouseleave by declaring $theTimeout globally in the script. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hah looks like your trying to build a fluid slider with a few options... I had just that idea some months ago, figures this isn't actually as easy as it seems. For starters we're using jQuery so we might as well write it in a plugin format since we'll need a scope in which we can declare and use variables that change over time at will...

I'll just cut to the chase; if you want to work with slides / pause them you need to be in control of the timeout id, store it and clear the timeout when needed to prevent the next slide animation...

Took me some figuring out but heres my working version having only some very basic functionality but you can at least start / stop it and do next/prev/rand:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RFJMy/218/

So if you want to make a plugin/functionality that does the things you describe you will need to rewrite a good part of your code to have a base that can actually handle interrupts in a logical sense.